# Reading directly from url - not working

Tags: java, url

In some code i use similar code to Oracle's tutorial: [Reading directly from a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html). Oracle's code also here below:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This code worked before but it doesnt anymore. Even if i try the exact same code, inputLine never has any value. I dont know if it has something to do with java versions or something elso but i would like to know why this happens, and what is a good alternative.

Comment: Any exception has not been thrown? Do you use ipv4 or ipv6?

Comment: seems to work using `https://www.oracle.com/` (with the `s` in `https`)

Comment: Try to surround your code with try-catch-finally or try-with resources blocks and re-run it

Answer (score 1):

If you replace http://www.oracle.com/ by http://www.google.com/ it works.

It's because a GET http://www.oracle.com/ gives

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

If you run

```
curl www.oracle.com
```

You obtain the same effect. You have to follow the redirect with

```
curl -L www.oracle.com
```

to obtain the html content. In Java, you also have to follow the redirect, such as in this article :

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle** -

> When you run the program, you should see, scrolling by in your command
>   window, the HTML commands and textual content from the HTML file
>   located at http://www.oracle.com/. Alternatively, the program might
>   hang or you might see an exception stack trace. If either of the
>   latter two events occurs, you may have to set the proxy host so that
>   the program can find the Oracle server.

- You can set the proxy host through the command line. Depending on
  your network configuration, you might also need to set the proxy
  port. If necessary, ask your system administrator for the name of the
  proxy host on your network.

**UNIX**

java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost
[-Dhttp.proxyPort=portNumber] URLReader

**DOS shell (Windows 95/NT)**

java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost
[-Dhttp.proxyPort=portNumber] URLReader

Also, I have actually ran it on my IDE but it only works with `HTTPS`

Answer (score 0):

As loris securo commented i needed to use https instead of http. And that fixed my problems.